# Possible to get desktop notifications for shared mailbox on outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Is there a way to get desktop alerts or notifications for when a new email is sent to a shared mailbox on outlook? I've tried looking around in rules and alert flags but none seem to give me the right result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

First you need to add your shared mailbox as an separate mailbox in Outlook. More information about how to add the shared mailbox to your outlook client as an separate account, please refer to my reply mentioned in this thread: [Send automatic replies, only to people outside your organization, from a shared mailbox?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/787503/send-automatic-replies-only-to-people-outside-your#:%7E:text=We%20just%20need%20to%20add%20the%20shared%20mailbox%20to%20your%20outlook%20client%20as%20an%20separate%20account%2C)

And then create a rule for the shared mailbox.

[image]